# Android: How to add a tool tip to the active tab in TabWidget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

What is the best way to add a tooltip to the active tab in the TabWidget?

[image]

Is there an easy way to draw this using xml shape? Or should I use a custom drawable?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the tooltip in your image? How do you want to trigger it?

Comment: It's the pointer tip underneath the active tab. When another tab is selected, I want it to have the tip and remove it from the inactive tab. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279647/display-view-on-top-of-action-bar/20479815#20479815)