# How can i show a view over my tabs (pointing to a menu item)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tooltip, android-tabs

I already did this tooltip:
[image]

But I need to show a tooltip pointing to a menu item in my actionbar (over the tabs), anybody can help me?
[image]

Comment: Finally I did it wrapping my main view. This was really helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279647/display-view-on-top-of-action-bar/20479815#20479815)