# Adding text hint to Android SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

How do I add a hint on the top of a listView like "Pull down to refresh" which is contained in a swipeRefreshLayout from android.support.v4.

The pull down to refresh works but I want to add a text whenever the user pulls the listview slightly down.

Comment: I want the same thing like this....

Comment: Any Update on this Q?

Answer (score 8):

---

EDIT 10/21/2014

If you update the support-v4 to the latest version (at least 21.0.0) you can use the built-in loading indicator!

---

I just came up with a simple, yet effective, solution.

The idea is to add a custom ViewGroup that grows its height when the SwipeRefreshLayout child gets pulled down. In this ViewGroup you will put everything you need for your hint (TextViews, ImageViews, ...).

I chose to extend a RelativeLayout because it makes easier to position your "hint" elements.

1) Create a custom widget as follows:

```
public class SwipeRefreshHintLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public SwipeRefreshHintLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeRefreshHintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwipeRefreshHintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setSwipeLayoutTarget(final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout) {

        final View swipeTarget = swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(0);
        if (swipeTarget == null) {
            return;
        }

        swipeTarget.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            private Rect oldBounds = new Rect(), newBounds = new Rect();

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                newBounds.set(swipeTarget.getLeft(), swipeRefreshLayout.getTop(), swipeTarget.getRight(), swipeTarget.getTop());

                if (!oldBounds.equals(newBounds)){
                    getLayoutParams().height = newBounds.height();
                    requestLayout();
                    oldBounds.set(newBounds);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

2) In your Fragment or Activity layout use this custom widget.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.widget.SwipeRefreshHintLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/label_swipe_to_refresh"/>

        <!-- Any other view positioned using RelativeLayout rules -->

    </com.example.widget.SwipeRefreshHintLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) Then, in your Activity onCreate() or in your Fragment onCreateView(), put those lines:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
mSwipeRefreshHintLayout = (SwipeRefreshHintLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_hint);
mSwipeRefreshHintLayout.setSwipeLayoutTarget(mSwipeRefreshLayout);
```

Done!

Comment: There is one minor issue though. The layout does not wait for the user to release the listview after pulling down before starting to refresh itself.
Only if you could correct that.

Comment: Also, it would be great if the text could be shown in the action bar instead of below it just like the stock e-mail app in Kitkat.

Comment: Hi Paul,
For the first question:
The automatic starting of the refresh is hardcoded in the library. If you want to customize it, you have to extend SwipeRefreshLayout and override onTouchEvent().
For the second question:
What you ask is a bit tricky. The ActionBar hasn't helper method to allow such animations. Using a solution similar to the one i proposed, you can lay a view over the ActionBar and proportionally animate its showing behavior.
See [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279647/display-view-on-top-of-action-bar

Comment: Pure genius! The only thing that I changed is that SwipeRefreshHintLayout extends LinearLayout because relative layout didn't work for me. Thanks

Comment: @araks Thanks for hint. But now I want set text dynamically to TextView while pulling down SwipeRefreshLayout. Please advice.

Comment: @Umesh just add android:id="@+id/hintTextView" to the TextView in the xml, then via code ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.hintTextView)).setText("Anything you'd like");

Comment: @araks, I am setting text in onRefresh(), but it set text only when I pull SwipeRefreshLayout to threshold distance and onRefresh() called. I want to set when SwipeRefreshLayout start dragging.

Comment: @Umesh you can do it in SwipeRefreshHintLayout class, in onPreDraw method:
if (!oldBounds.equals(newBounds)){ 
// Set text here
...
}
You can also use a boolean variable as a flag to set text only once, to avoid setting text multiple times in onDraw method!

Comment: In order to use in conjunction with the built-in indicator, change `getLayoutParams().height = newBounds.height();` to `if (newBounds.height() < 0) {
                        getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                    } else {
                        getLayoutParams().height = newBounds.height();
                    }`