# Adding descriptive text for SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swipe

Luckily, Android team has added the [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) to its Support Library.
That's a cool feature, but I would like to add a sort of "descriptive text" inside this widget, that appears while the user moves down the list and the refresh process has not yet started.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there anything ready for this special widget? Or I need to do all the job by myself?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html)? You can get that textview by its id in activity, and cange text while data is being refreshed.

Comment: Please refer - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096793/adding-text-hint-to-android-swiperefreshlayout)